# PHP copy command folder

Tags: php

My currency working directory is ../main

I have a script which accepts files to be uploaded.

I have the following code but instead of coping the file into the ../_assets folder, it copies it into the ../main folder with the filename as ../_assets/correct.csv.

Any idea what might be wrong here?

Thanks

```
const IMPORT_FILE_DIR  = "..\_assets\\";

private $file_name   = "";

$this->file_name = Page::IMPORT_FILE_DIR . $_FILES['file_in']['name'];
$result= copy( $_FILES['file_in']['tmp_name'],$this->file_name);
```

Here fileName is = "..\_assets\correct2.csv"

Comment: _It may be a silly Question but_ Why are you not using `move_uploaded_file()` to do this

Comment: Are you sure this code is part of a form processing script and not a later script?

Comment: In short you are a bit short on relevant information for us to do much more than play 20 question here

Comment: beacuse move_uploaded_file() is returning 1 but is not moving the file at all for some reason.

Comment: yes it is part of the form processing script and executing but uploading to the wrong folder instead thats the issue.